# Unable to access kubectl api inside pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

> Unable to access kubectl Inside pod . I have created a service account
> and created corresponding roles and role bindings as well .  kubectl
> binary file is also installed inside the image of pod . But on
> applying any kubectl commands inside the pod is giving me the
> following error . The connection to the server localhost:8080 was
> refused - did you specify the right host or port?
>
> because the secret token is not mounted inside
> var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io./
>
> bash: cd: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io: No such file or directory

```
**service account** 
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-kenable
  namespace: "{{.Release.Namespace}}"
  labels:
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: "{{.Release.Namespace}}"
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-kenablerole
  labels:
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods", "pods/exec"]
  verbs: ["create", "delete", "get", "list", "patch", "watch"]
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-kenablerolebinding
  namespace: "{{.Release.Namespace}}"
  labels:
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-kenable
  namespace: "{{.Release.Namespace}}"
  apiGroup: ""
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-kenablerole
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

---

```
***** statefulset.yaml*****


  name: webapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  serviceName: webappservice
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      serviceAccountName: {{ .Release.Name }}-kenable
      automountServiceAccountToken: true
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: k8s.gcr.io/nginx-slim:0.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: web
        volumeMounts:
        - name: www
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: www
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

NOTE : I am not using deployment type file for my project

on describing the pod
The mounts has the following

```
    Mounts:
      *** removed the other mounts from here for security reasons**
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from demo-di-kenable-token-m85lz (ro)

Volumes:
 
  demo-di-kenable-token-m85lz:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  demo-di-kenable-token-m85lz
    Optional:    false
```

but on doing

```
kubectl exec -n demo test-di  -- ls -la /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
ls: cannot access /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount: No such file or directory
```

kubectl version of pod

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.0", GitCommit:"cb303e613a121a29364f75cc67d3d580833a7479", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-04-08T16:31:21Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
bash-4.2# exit
```

kubectl version of cluster

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.5", GitCommit:"e338cf2c6d297aa603b50ad3a301f761b4173aa6", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-12-09T11:18:51Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.5", GitCommit:"e338cf2c6d297aa603b50ad3a301f761b4173aa6", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-12-09T11:10:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}


kubectl exec -it <podname> -- printenv | grep http://kubernetes
---> Got no result for this 


KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443 
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443
```

Comment: Hi. Please edit your question and format the code correctly. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited . You can check now .

Comment: Can you show the code that's trying to invoke the Kubernetes API?  (I'd expect to see calls via a language-native Kubernetes SDK, not calls to `kubectl` typically.)

Comment: Can you show a `mount` from your container? You don't have anything in `/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount`? Can you check the Pod created by your StatefulSet: is the `automountServiceAccountToken=true` still there?

Comment: i have added the mounts along with the question now

Comment: How did you set up your cluster? Did you use bare metal or some cloud providor? Which version of Kubernetes did you use?

Comment: How are you trying to access API? Why localhost:8080?

Comment: the kubectl API is already installed inside the pod

Comment: try running `kubectl exec -it <podname> -- printenv|grep KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` and share the output

Comment: `localhost:8080` seems not correct place to access API server from within the pod.

Comment: Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.0", GitCommit:"cb303e613a121a29364f75cc67d3d580833a7479", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-04-08T16:31:21Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: kubectl -n demo-sdl exec -it test-di -- printenv|grep KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.254.0.1

Comment: Your code should try to access this . You can grep for PORT to for api server port.

Comment: Or just `http://kubernetes`

Comment: our code should try to access this . You can grep for PORT to for api server por -----> can you give the entire command ?

Comment: KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443

Comment: Did you try `kubectl exec -it <podname> -- printenv | grep PORT` and `kubectl exec -it <podname> -- printenv | grep http://kubernetes`? Please paste the result to the question (not in the comment).

Comment: updated in question

Comment: could you run `kubectl config view` and paste the results?

Comment: Plase also provide valid yamls. Your statefulset yaml is incomplete and second `spec` field is in the wrong place.